# Training caffe library and Loss does not converge

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, gradient-descent

I use [caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/) for my recognition and I have an issue that loss data never converge.

My training parameters in the configuration are

```
      Conf.base_lr = 0.2;          
      Conf.max_iter = 800001;
      Conf.test_iter = 100;
      Conf.test_interval = 1000;
      Conf.momentum = 0.5;
      Conf.random_seed = 2;
      Conf.clip_gradients = 0.1;
      Conf.gamma = 0.8;
      Conf.stepsize = 100000;
      Conf.weights = "";
      //logging
      Conf.display_interval = 100;
      Conf.snapshot_prefix_folder = "../tmp";
      Conf.snapshot_interval = 10000;
      Conf.schematic_path = "../tmp/reinspect.png";
      Conf.graph_prefix = "../tmp/history";
      Conf.log_file = "../tmp/log_brainwash.txt";
      Conf.graph_interval = 500;
      //net
      Conf.init_range = 0.1;
```

Then when I check Backward data

```
All net params (data, diff): L1 norm = (208684, 3.43485e+11); L2 norm = (135.231, 3.96399e+08)
```

Diff values of L1 and L2 norms are huge and not normal. What could be wrong with my parameters in configuration and how to tune them?

Some of my log data for forward and backward can be seen in this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/y894qaie3ef5p21/AAAGufgDjuGu6ne9zDx5O9eCa?dl=0).

EDIT:

Previously I have problem of some layers are not included in the Backward propagation. So now I force them and all are included except these with no bottom layers like Input and DummyData. They are shown below.
This development is similar implementation to this [Lib](https://github.com/Russell91/apollocaffe) (only Python and C++ are different). They include all those layers in Backward propagation, DummyData is NumpyData in Python in their implementation. If necessary, how to include those into Backward propagation.

```
layer {
  name: "image"
  type: "Input"
  top: "image"
  input_param { shape: { dim: 1 dim: 3 dim: 480 dim: 640 } }
}
layer {
  name: "box_flags"
  type: "Input"
  top: "box_flags"
  input_param { shape: { dim: 300 dim: 1 dim: 5 dim: 1 } }
}

layer {
  name: "boxes"
  type: "Input"
  top: "boxes"
  input_param { shape: { dim: 300 dim: 4 dim: 5 dim: 1 } }
}


layer {
  name: "lstm_hidden_seed"
  type: "DummyData"  
  top: "lstm_hidden_seed"
  dummy_data_param {
    shape { dim: 300 dim: 250 }  
    data_filler { type: "constant" value: 0 } 
  }
}
layer {
  name: "lstm_mem_seed"
  type: "DummyData"  
  top: "lstm_mem_seed"
  dummy_data_param {
    shape { dim: 300 dim: 250 }  
    data_filler { type: "constant" value: 0 } 
  }
}
```

DummyData layer was NumpyData when it was in Python, when I convert to C++, it is changed to DummyData with initialization data 0.

Do I need to include all those Input and DummyData into Backward propagation?
I still have this abnormal big values at L1 and L2 norm.

```
[Backward] All net params (data, diff): L1 norm = (208696, 4.09333e+06); L2 norm = (135.23, 4791.7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your learning  rate is very high, making your optimization process diverge. Try reduce it by factor of at least 50 and re-start the training.

Comment: Thanks, do my L1 norm and L2 norm diff values make sense? Even I changed learning rate to 0.004, I still have very high diff values of 10^+10. Is that make sense?

Comment: @batuman no. these are extremely large values. Are you getting these values right from the first iteration?

Comment: yes, I am getting after a few iterations like L1 norm = (208684, 1.00823e+06); L2 norm = (135.231, 1157.83). Where could be wrong?

Comment: @batuman this means your gradients explode rapidly. (1) Try `base_lr: 1e-5`. (2) init your weights with lower std. (3) decrease your `loss_weight` of your loss layer.

Comment: Sorry. Where do I do weight initialization? Where can I decrease loss_weight? I have these values in the update  momentum=0.5,  clip_gradients=0.1,  weight_decay=0.0, base_lr=1e-5,  gamma=0.8,  iterator,  stepsize=100000

Comment: @batuman are you starting training from scratch (random weights), or are you fine-tuning an already trained model?

Comment: I am implementing this (https://github.com/Russell91/apollocaffe) apollocaffe in C++. The library is written in Python for upper level APIs. I converted all to C++. Apollocaffe is basically sort of another way of implementation to Caffe, but it doesn't need constructing layers in initialization. It creates all layer dynamically one after another. That is the only difference. Features are extracted using GoogleNet and using the features Apollocaffe uses LSTM for recognition.

Comment: @batuman dynamically or statically constructing the net: where are your weights coming from? are you loading a caffemodel file or are you initializing them randomly?

Comment: Yes, I load the googlenet model (bvlc_googlenet.caffemodel). Since it has issue with Backward propagation (those L1, L2 are in backward), do you think my implementation has some issue at backward?

Comment: @batuman reccurrent nets may suffer from exploding/vanishing gradients and need careful tuning. I suggest you start with very low base_lr and see if the gradients behave

Comment: Thanks Shai, i'll explore and update the fingings. I think I have some errors somewhere in translating dynamic network to caffe style prototxt.

Comment: I have updated in EDIT. NumpyData was the layer under Python and I converted to DummyData in C++. Is that make sense?